# Include Core CSS in one particular file in YII

Tags: php, css, yii

I disabled core css file because it was intercepting with my custom css files:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->scriptMap = array(
    '*.css' => false,
);
```

Now, I need core css files in one view only.

Is there anyway to include those core css files in one view?

Comment: you can use register package, to include core css, use registerPackage() on particular page,,, make a core Css package

Comment: are you talking abt ..... screen.css, print, ie, main, form css files ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this**

**In config/main.php  under components section**

```
  'clientScript'=>array(
        'packages'=>array(
            'CoreCss'=>array(
                 'baseUrl'=> 'css/' ,
                  'css'=>array('main.css','ie.css','form.css','screen.css','print.css'),
            ),
        ),
```

**In any page you want to register this css use below lines..**

```
 $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
 $cs->registerPackage('CoreCss');
```

may be this things can help you...